# Convert Scala countvectorizer output to libsvm format

Tags: scala, format, libsvm, countvectorizer

Hi I Could anyone suggest a mapping from scala countvectorizer output: ([label, (nVocab, [i1, i2, ...], [c1, c2, ...])]) to the libsvm format: (label, : : ...) ?

if you take the input as a string, I am not sure where to split to get the fields, for starters.

Alternatively, is there a scala utility for this?
Thanks,
kvd

Answer (score 0):

I fingured this out. The countVectorizer output could be cast into sparseVecor data type, which has [size, [indices], [values]]. The indices and values arrays could be zipped and output in the libsvm format.

val countVec   = vec(1).asInstanceOf[SparseVector]

Upon further exploration it turns out that I don't need this conversion. I could create a Labeled point using the classLabel and the sparseVector and pass to the machine learning object directly.

Thanks,
kvd